# Как создать файл в файловой системе iOS при помощи Qt?

Tags: ios, qt, файловая-система

Если запускать такой код на десктопе, то file.txt успешно создатся.

```
void main_window::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
  QFile file("file.txt");
  if(file.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text))
  {
    file.write("text");
    file.close();
  }
}
```

Если этот же код запускать на iOS-устройстве, то проходим мимо ветки `if(file.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text))`

Как создать файл на iOS-устройстве с помощью Qt?

Comment: Если `open` вернул `false`, выведете в логи ошибку через [errorString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#errorString): `qDebug() << file.errorString();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS и другие мобильные платформы работают в песочнице, Вы не можете просто так брать и создавать файлы там где Вам захотелось. Их можно создавать лишь в специально отведённых папках. Какие это папки на iOS, я, честно говоря, не знаю — Documents какие-нибудь и ещё что-то, смотрите документацию.

---

Для нахождения доступных приложению путей можно использовать [QStandardPaths](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html#details) класс.

Comment: Все верно... Работать с файлами можно только в рамках самого Приложения. То есть в приложение пишите и читайте что хотите, остальное закрыто. NSFileManager вам поможет выяснить где лежит ваше приложение :)

Comment: Тогда каким образом в Qt-коде вызвать NSFileManager? В Qt, как я понимаю, есть аналог NSFileManage в виде QDir. QDir::currentPath() возвращает текущий каталог, в котором нельзя создавать файлы. При этом перейти на уровень вверх с помощью метода QDir::cdUp() удаётся, но получить список каталогов по такому пути при момощи QDir::entryInfoList() не получается.

Comment: @ArtyomSorokoumov, обновил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, @ixSci! Такой вариант кода прекрасно работает:

```
void main_window::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
  QString filename = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::GenericDataLocation);
  filename.append("/text.txt");
  QFile file(filename);
  if(file.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text))
  {
    file.write("text");
    file.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: [здесь](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW2) подробней описано о файловой системе iOS